# Custom wifi driver for android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

in android, we can provide Wifi driver either as a module or built in kernel, what is the difference between them. And how to choose them?

Comment: what do you mean "how to choose them"? do you mean how to disable or enable?

Comment: I mean: should we provider wifi driver as a module or build in kernel in own platform. what we can base on to choice.

Comment: I am having similar question as above . If i want to add new USB WIFI dongle to my phone using OTG connector , then what should be better way . Should i provide wifi driver as built in kernel or load it whenever required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the module, you need to manually load it with `insmod` to use it.
Then you can lookup the modules in the system with `lsmod`.

With it built in the driver, system loads it automatically on system start.

You can choose them when you build the linux kernel in menuconfig. Either you want it built   into the kernel or not.

In android the wifi module is loaded into system when you go to the settings and select to   turn on wifi. When you select to turn it off, it removes the wifi module by calling a function similar to `rmmod`.